# Show that $A = \bigcup C$ for some $C \subset B$ iff for every $a \in A$ there exists $b \in B$ such that $a\in b$ and $b \subset A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show that $A = \bigcup C$ for some $C \subset B$ iff for every $a \in A$ there exists $b \in B$ such that $a\in b$ and $b \subset A$

I am having trouble proving the right-to-left implication, but have proved the left-to-right implication.

Could anyone provide guidance?

Comment: Just to be sure, you meant $b\subset B$, didn't you?

Comment: @KimJongUn No. $b \subset A$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A = \bigcup C$ for some $C \subset B$. Let $a \in A$. Then $a \in \bigcup C$ which means (by definition of $\bigcup C$) that there is some $c \in C$, such that $a \in c$. But as $C \subset B$, this $c \in C$ is also in $B$, so we can set $b = c$. And as $b = c \subset \bigcup C = A$, $b \subset A$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

**Right-to-left**: for each $a\in A$, let $b_a\in B$ be such that $a\in b_a$ and $b_a\subset A$. Let $C=\bigcup_a\{b_a\}$. Then, $A=\bigcup C$ where $C\subset B$.

p.s. You might think of $B$ as a topology, $A$ as an open set, and $b$ as an open neighborhood.